# Почему PhpStorm не показывает ошибку в коде?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет

Есть такая функция:

```
<script>
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
        var id = location.hash, targ=$(id+'+section.module'); //запоминаем в targ нужный блок
        if (!targ[0]) return // выходим, если "левый" хэш, например, ввели вручную
        var top = targ.offset().top;
        $(".header__list a").removeClass(('active'));
        $('.header__list a[href="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
    //
    // if (windowRes <= 1024) {
    //  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top})
    // }

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: top + 3
    }, 1500);
    });
    }).on('load', function(){$(window).hashchange()}) // переходим к нужному разделу, если, напрмер, ссылку в новой вкладке открыли
</script>
```

Веб-инспектор кричит об ошибке: joxi.ru/4AkzJvnHBlen2q

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: не пользуйся PhpStorm :) Тут кстати и кроме этого еще и `});` лишний

Comment: А че не в поддержку phpstorm, там же очень отзывчивые ребята

Comment: @Grundy Можете, пожалуйста, переписать правильно функцию? Я ее копипастнул и не вник в смысл. Пробовал переписать, но ломается лоигка

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Я думаю проблема в том, что JS в index.html, поэтому и не видит ошибку

Comment: может вы проверки отключили просто? у меня все отлично показывает https://goo.gl/vxeuYK

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Вроде как нет, ничего не трогал

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов а покажите скрин этого куска кода у себя из phpStorm

Comment: @ИванПшеницын http://joxi.ru/8AnzMGkHgWMDAO - вот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая [ваш сриншот](http://joxi.ru/8AnzMGkHgWMDAO), я пришел к выводу, что все нужные code inspections у вас активны. У себя мне не удалось воспроизвести проблему отключением каких бы то ни было проверок.

Я нашел только один способ добиться такого, как у вас внешнего вида кода - убрав цветное подчеркивание в code style. Проверьте эти настройки у себя: https://goo.gl/zL4mt1 (Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Errors and Warnings -> Error). Они должны быть такими же. Если галочек справа нет или цвет не контрастный - получается ситуация как у вас.

Если это не поможет - мое мнение, что проблема в глюке шторма или плагинов.

**Верный код,** в вашем случае, будет примерно таким, если я правильно его понял:

```
<script>
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
        var id = location.hash,
            targ = $(id+'+section.module'); //запоминаем в targ нужный блок

        if (!targ[0]) return; // выходим, если "левый" хэш, например, ввели вручную

        var top = targ.offset().top;
        $(".header__list a").removeClass(('active'));
        $('.header__list a[href="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');

        //
        // if (windowRes <= 1024) {
        //  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top})
        // }

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: top + 3
        }, 1500);
    }).on('load', function(){$(window).trigger('hashchange')}); // переходим к нужному разделу, если, напрмер, ссылку в новой вкладке открыли
</script>
```

Для меня осталось загадкой, откуда там скобки в середине блока кода и странные `})` в конце.

Comment: Мне бы код переписать на правильный лад)
У меня не вышло

Comment: По ошибке - вроде все круто http://joxi.ru/eAOeJl9UqDB5mo

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов тогда у меня нет идей, почему ошибки не показывает. Попробуйте переустановить) Версия, кстати, актуальная? А код в чем сложность поправить - по строкам читаешь код и смотришь где неожиданные скобки и все делов.

Comment: Да не всего делов, не выходит переписать. Последняя строка все ломает. Можешь глянуть?

Comment: Предпоследняя версия, вроде как

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов а ты выше глянь;) я в ответ уже добавил. Последняя строка ломает: ты же прочитал весь блок кода от начала и знаешь, что должны закрыться только одна `}` и одна `)`. Убираешь лишние и все. Там было что-то типа `});})`

Comment: Эх, что за дела http://joxi.ru/zANeNy9U5y4D29.

Comment: опять и снова ошибка)

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов это да, я тоже не знаю, где вы взяли этот код)) Исправил в ответе на то, что, вероятно, имелось ввиду.

Comment: Не помогло( Блин, не знаю как, но вчера работало

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43802/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm 2017.3.4/manjaro

Галочка на пункте "Power Save Mode" может привести к отключению функций подсказки и проверки синтаксиса. Уберите её.